# re-apply class to ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to re-apply classes to new content loaded via ajax.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="link_1">link_1</a>
<a href="#" id="link_2">link_2</a>
<a href="#" id="link_3">link_3</a>
    <a href="#" id="ajax-load">load more</a>

<ul id="list">
    <li class="li-one">one content</li>
    <li class="li-two">two content</li>
    <li class="li-three">three content</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#link_1').live('click', function() {
                $('.li-one').addClass('hide');
            });
            $('#link_2').live('click', function() {
                $('.li-two').addClass('hide');
            });
            $('#link_3').live('click', function() {
                $('.li-three').addClass('hide');
            });
            $('#load-ajax').click(function() {
               $.get('http://link', function(data) {
               $('#list').append(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Ajax HTML page code:

```
<li class="li-one">one content</li>
<li class="li-two">two content</li>
<li class="li-three">three content</li>
```

**ToDo:**

user clicks link_1 -> 'li-one' get 'hidden' class -> user click ajax -> ajax loads BUT all 'li-one' with 'hidden' class

user clicks link_2 -> 'li-two' get 'hidden' class -> user click ajax -> ajax loads BUT all 'li-two' with 'hidden' class

user clicks link_3 -> 'li-three' get 'hidden' class -> user click ajax -> ajax loads BUT all 'li-three' with 'hidden' class

It should work like a filter.

Comment: Then where is your ajax?

Comment: If you just want to add classes then you don't need ajax.

Comment: well just add the line $('.li-one').addClass('hide'); after your ajax calls. I don't think there's a way to 'tell it in advance'. Or you can create a default callback that you stick to each ajax callback.  I'm a little worried to see no ajax there though

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems as though every time you are loading in content that has the class `li-one` you are not wanting it displayed?

Why not just change the style of `li-one` to be hidden by default, then only show it when you need?

Answer (score 0):

Use the call back function in AJAX to .addClass to the relevant link.

http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/5-jquery-add-variables-to-ajax-callback.html

See the function(data){} that is being called

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Put a callback when the data is loaded and added to document and call again: $('.li-one').addClass('hide');

But, let me optimize the code:

```
function startList() {
    $('ul#list li').live('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('hide');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    startList()
});
```

When you load the data, you can call `startList()` to make the new data work on it.